# create instance from template in google compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I feel silly, but I can't find this anywhere.

I've created some "instance templates" for VMs in Google Compute Engine, but I can't find a button anywhere that says "Create an instance from this template" (or the equivalent).

I've looked on the "create instance" pages and on the "template" pages.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that behavior is expected.

[Instance templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#instance_templates) can only be used as part of [managed instance groups](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances). They define the properties (machine type, image, zone, etc.) of instances created in the managed instance group. They cannot be used to create a stand-alone VM (I guess you could create a managed instance group of size 1).

> ### [Instance Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#instance_templates)
>
> Instance templates define the machine type, image, zone, and other
>   instance properties for the instances in a [managed instance
>   group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances). A managed instance group uses an instance template to
>   create or update the instances that are part of the group. You can
>   create an instance template once and can reuse it for multiple groups
>   and configuration.
>
> An instance template is a global resource that is not bound to a zone
>   or a region. However, you can still specify some zonal resources in an
>   instance template, which restricts the template to the zone where that
>   resource resides. For example, if you include a read-only persistent
>   disk from `us-central1-b` in your instance template, you cannot use
>   that template in any other zone because that specific disk exists only
>   in zone `us-central1-b`. For more information about zonal resources,
>   read [Regions and Zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones).
>
> To learn how to create an instance template, read [Creating Instance
>   Templates](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates).

The most common application for instance templates is to use it with micro-service architectures where you define how a pool of identical backend VMs for the service should be created and size adjusted based on the load.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is no longer correct.

Now you can create a VM instance from an Instance template. The following screenshot shows the "CREATE VM" button.

[Creating a VM Instance from an Instance Template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template)

[image: Instance Templte Create VM]

Answer (score 1):

Instance Templates are primarily used as a blueprint for Managed Instance Groups.

> A managed instance group contains identical instances that you can manage as a single entity. Managed instance groups support autoscaling, load balancing, rolling updates, and more.

See more info here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances